# Constraining typescript interface keys and values

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I am trying to use an interface that is declared few times with different key-value pairs and I want to restrict its keys to a template literal and values to a given generic type. This interface will be later used to define function input. I tried to check if key extends string, and it seemed to work but I was able to pass anything as a key, even number.

Here is the snippet of what I'd like to achieve:

```
// restrict interface keys and values
interface Test{
    [k: string | number | symbol]: typeof k extends `${infer Prefix}@${infer Suffix}` ? { prefix: Prefix, suffix: Suffix } : never
}

interface Test{
    'test1@test': { prefix: 'test1', suffix: 'test' }, // this throws, but shouldnt
}

interface Test{
    'test2@test': { prefix: 'test2', suffix: 'test' }, // this throws, but shouldnt
}
```

Comment: Not possible without a function to do the inferencing, which would look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w23D8N).

Comment: There is no specific type in TypeScript that works this way; `typeof k` is always just `string | number | symbol`; it is not generic.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do with multiple definitions of `Test` though; are you intending to use interface [merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)?  I mean, why not just define your interface like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqkG2w)?  If you're not using interface merging, what *are* you trying to do?

Comment: @caTS, yeah, that makes sense for `const foo: Test = {'test1@test': ...}`, but they wrote `interface Test { 'test1@test: ...}`, like declaration merging or something.  Which is... ‍♂️.  Is it just checking that an interface matches a pattern?  Or what?  I'm confused here.

Comment: @jcalz - this is exactly what I am trying to do. Each declaration will hold api routes and request props and all of them merged will be used to type functions like f.e. fetch. And what I am trying to achieve is to force keys matching template literals and values matching some given type.

Comment: As far as I know you can't get declaration merging to give you error messages at the merge point this way.  You can get an error elsewhere, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3X01W).  Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz - I think we could go with what you proposed. The answer is good enough to satisfy my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's unfortunately no way to constrain an interface the way you're trying to do here, at least not so that errors will appear directly on the lines you don't like.  All my attempts ran afoul of circularity detectors, like

```
type CheckTest = { [K in keyof Test]: 
  K extends `${infer P}@${infer S}` ? { prefix: P, suffix: S } : never 
};
interface Test extends CheckTest { } // error, circular!
```

Even if that didn't error, there's no `implements` clause for interfaces, so the constraint would be hard to represent directly.  There's an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#24274](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24274), and the workarounds listed in there are illegally circular, at least when I apply them here.

---

The closest I can think of is a line that checks whether `Test` is valid according to your rules, and which results in a compiler error at or near that line if there's a problem.  This error will hopefully contain enough information for someone to find and fix the offending member of `Test`, although this is made less pleasant when you are using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) and your members of `Test` are scattered throughout your code base.

Oh well, let's at least look at it:

```
type CheckTest = {
    [K in keyof Test]: K extends `${infer P}@${infer S}` ?
    { prefix: P, suffix: S } : never
};

type VerifyTest<T extends Test = CheckTest> = T;
// ----------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^ <----- IS THERE AN ERROR HERE?
// if so, then some member of Test is bad. 
// The error will tell you which one and what's wrong
```

The `CheckTest` type is similar to your definition except that it actually [maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the properties of `Test` instead of trying to use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) which treats the key as a single thing (`typeof k` is just `string | number | symbol` and not the specific keys of `Test`).

Anyway, `CheckTest` should be assignable to `Test` if `Test` is valid.  Then the `VerifyTest` definition just assumes it's valid, by using `CheckTest` in a type position that needs to be assignable to `Test`.

---

Let's test it out.  First we have this:

```
interface Test {
    'test1@test': { prefix: 'test1', suffix: 'test' }
}

interface Test {
    'test2@test': { prefix: 'test2', suffix: 'test' }
}

// ...

type VerifyTest<T extends Test = CheckTest> = T; // okay
```

No error, so we're good.  Then someone comes along and does a bad thing:

```
interface Test {
    'foo@bar': { prefix: "oof", suffix: "bar" }
}
```

And suddenly

```
type VerifyTest<T extends Test = CheckTest> = T;  // error!
// ----------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~
/* The types of ''foo@bar'.prefix' are incompatible between these types.
    Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '"oof"' */
```

Which lets you know that it's time to find `"foo"`/`"oof"` in your code base and fix it.

---

Not pretty, but it's the closest I can get.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-XddIDfuyTSmRyM8K+EbnHKlWqtU1eRaSDaHQgXR6AyGwBGNomKZf3-A4FmWVZSF7NcJDGXc9n0Q4TGOJBTguGgrlueJSAeZAXhoN4PlYb5fg-L982BC8wT4SFoVheFEVoK0aAAQhNLECQ4zicWJMkyQpKlaUcYU2S5HlmX5QVhNFTgJQaBUZTlKUlRVdUbWfNsdSQPVDRIM1kEY607UdZ1XWdD0vR9P00ADINsFtdJQy4cNIxjLDxQAKkcc0cJ6TUuC4ec0EXEBlwNcsFGMELkAoeBFTgSgyFVB1kHVShbQgT8XUyKBkB8g0IN0s8DHXQL12MTTgDQNgQCgKAyCjUAktytAXSKrhN3qMqkHcuFY3jIA)